# How can i make the sidebar responsive?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have two problems in this code

The first one is  making the currentLocation component appears on top of the sidebar component

The second one is that the sidebar is not responsive(mobile first approach)

can anyone help me  please?

[Code to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-hoover-wdgc6)

Comment: Hi Hassene. You'll get a better response if you include your code in the question itself, and if you ask more specific questions. What have you tried so far, and what is it that isn't working with it?

Comment: @Hassene, can you describe what exactly is wrong with currentLocation component and the result that you're trying to achieve? Also, can you describe how you would like to see your sidebar on a mobile phone?

Answer (score 1):

[Here you go](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-ride-tpd64)

1. currentLocation component appears on top of the sidebar component
2. The sidebar is now responsive (mobile first approach)

Notes: I have kept some of the colors and styles from your original it seems they were chosen to be those. It is set to hit a break points on small screens to go full width otherwise it takes 4 out of 12 columns of the screen. The class you would look for to change this is `col-sm-4` Hope I was of help to you.

Happy coding!